# Como diminuir valores no banco de dados de outra tabela, depois de realizar um insert

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, sql-update, sql-select

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `saida` (`nomeProduto`, `quantidadeProduto`, `pa`, `setor`, `dataSaida`) VALUES (
    '$nomeProduto', $quantidadeProduto, '$pa', '$setor', '$dataSaida')";
$inserir = mysqli_query($conexao, $sql);
```

Exemplo após eu realizar esse insert, gostaria de diminuir automaticamente o valor da quantidade produtos disponíveis em `estoque_produto`, como eu posso realizar essa operação de subtração ? e verificação.

Exemplo não posso dar saída de produto pois a quantidade e insuficiente ou zero

Comment: Use um [trigger](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-trigger.html)

Comment: pq não faz um update em seguida?

Answer (score 2):

Você pode criar uma trigger para que quando seja inserido um registro na tabela saida, o valor da tabela estoque_produto seja atualizado. Exemlo:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER `saida_after_insert`     
AFTER INSERT ON `saida`     
FOR EACH ROW     
begin
  UPDATE estoque_produto SET 
 estoque_produto.quantidade - NSERTED.quantidade
  WHERE
   estoque_produto.nomeProduto = INSERTED.nomeProduto;
end
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pelo feedback @Assis Zang.